# Fill section of contour with solid color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a contour plot with some z values equal to zero. I want to shade all these values a particular color, from this

[image: incomplete]

to this (MS Paint mock-up).

[image: complete]

How can I go about doing so? Is there some feature in the library that will allow me to do this?

Comment: You would draw a filled contour (=`contourf`) plot of the contour you like to shade. Note that this question does not comply to [ask]. You should clearly state what problem you have and in how far other resources are not helping. If you have a problem with implementing anything using `contourf` you need to show the [mcve] of the code that fails in doing so.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. I did a `contourf` for the gray fill followed by a `contour` for the contour lines. The only problem is that the gray fill overlaps some of the lines. Is there a way to fix this? I want to draw the contour lines over the gray fill.

Comment: I have no way of knowing what you did and how the resulting plot looks like. I can only give you advice on reproducible code, again, see [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `matplotlib` contourplot and colormap demos. From the contour plot demo's last example, you can specify a colour map for the contour plot as follows

```
plt.figure()
# plots a bunch of colours
im = plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='bilinear', origin='lower',
                cmap=cm.gray, extent=(-3, 3, -2, 2))

# plot the contour lines 
levels = np.arange(-1.2, 1.6, 0.2)
CS = plt.contour(Z, levels,
                 origin='lower',
                 linewidths=2,
                 extent=(-3, 3, -2, 2))
```

you'll need to define your own color map if you want to leave some regions white/unfilled. The colormap is just a `dict` that maps numeric values to colours

https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html

https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html

Comment: No, `imshow` does not seem to be well suited here. As commented above, using `contourf` would be the way to go.